# Python paramiko.transport:[chan 1] EOF sent (1)

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I try to run command on a remote machine through SSH.

```
import os
import paramiko

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

connection = paramiko.SSHClient()
connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
connection.load_system_host_keys()

connection.connect("10.42.207.4", username='d', password='d')
stdin, stdout, stderr = connection.exec_command("ls")
response = stdout.readlines()
errormsg = stderr.read()

stdin.close()
stdout.close()
stderr.close()

print response
```

This is the output:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x39077ed0L
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:[u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa', u'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:[u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc'] server encrypt:[u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc'] client mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com'] server mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com'] client compress:[u'zlib', u'none'] server compress:[u'zlib', u'none'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ciphers agreed: local=blowfish-cbc, remote=blowfish-cbc
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local blowfish-cbc, remote blowfish-cbc; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key 5bb99b2eb17675516583413910238cb4
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Authentication type (publickey) not permitted.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Allowed methods: [u'password']
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key 5bb99b2eb17675516583413910238cb4 in /home/ecsager/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Authentication type (publickey) not permitted.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Allowed methods: [u'password']
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
INFO:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 1 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] EOF sent (1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
stdin, stdout, stderr = connection.exec_command("ls\r")
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/client.py", line 311, in exec_command
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/channel.py", line 212, in exec_command
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/channel.py", line 1082, in _wait_for_event
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
```

Could somebody tell me what is the problem.
As I read may of the comments there should be some problem with the `\n` in the `exec_command` but I did not find the reason and the solution.

Comment: It looks like the remote system failed to execute the command, so the channel closed immediately. Can you do the same thing with the `ssh` command-line utility? What happens when you run `ssh d@10.42.207.4 ls` on the host where you're running this script? (Assuming the client system is unix or has an `ssh` command installed)

Comment: @Kenster It was a good idea. The ssh server does not support the X11 port forwarding. Is it possible to disable it in paramiko and is SSH? Why and where is it set to default?